# Unable to select an element from dropdown list in an React web page using Robotframework selenium

Tags: reactjs, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to automate an react web page using selenium2library and Robotframework. While trying to select an element from a list, selenium could not locate the value/ index in the list.
Code used to select the element

Inspect of the list element.

```
<div class="tab-content tab-content-custom">
    <div id="basic0" class="tab-pane fade provision-tab in active">
        <form class="col-md-12 center-form-container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">ThemePark</label>
                <div>
                    <select class="form-control" name="factory">
                        <option index="0" value="">Select a ThemePark</option>
                        <option index="1" value="2018061109361161">Wonderla Kochi</option>
                        <option index="2" value="2018061109394722">Wonderla Bangalore</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code used to select the element from the list.

```
Click Element    //*[@id="basic0"]/form/div/diventer code here
Sleep    2s
Capture Page Screenshot
Click Element    //*[@id="basic2018061109361161"]/form/div[1]/div/select
Wait Until Page Contains Element    //select[@name="factory"]    timeout=60s
Select From List By Value   //select[@name="factory"]   2018061109361161
```

Also tried 'Select From List By Index' and 'Select From List By Label', but all the options are throwing error that 'unable to find the value / index/ label in the selected element.

Comment: You're looking for an id of `basic2018061109361161`, but I don't see anything in that HTML with that id.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("select.form-control > option[value='2018061109361161']").click()
```